# Get undefined of Template reference (ng-template) in custom structural directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am using angular version-11 and learning custom-structural-directives.

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

interface Data {
loading: string;
}

 interface LoadingContext {
 $implicit: string;
 }


  @Directive({
  selector: '[appMyDirective]',
  })
  export class CustomDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
  private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
  private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}

  // the template reference input
 @Input() appMyDirectiveLoading!: TemplateRef<LoadingContext>;

 @Input('appMyDirective') set directiveInput(data: Data) {
 // here i get undefined if i try to get access to the appMyDirectiveLoading templateRef
    console.log(this.appMyDirectiveLoading) // undefined
 this._viewContainer.clear();
 this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
  this.appMyDirectiveLoading,{
    $implicit: data.loading // or 'hello world' 
   })
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
 // here everything just works fine
 console.log(appMyDirectiveLoading) // templateRef
 this._viewContainer.clear();
 this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
  this.appMyDirectiveLoading, {
    $implicit: 'hello world'
  })
 }


}
```

In app.component.html using my custom structural directive passing the data$ Observable along with template reference

```
<div 
*appMyDirective="(data$ | async)!; loading: loadingTemplate"
>

</div>
```

Here is the ng-template in the same app.component.html file

```
 <ng-template #loadingTemplate let-loading>
    <h2>{{ loading }}</h2>
 </ng-template>
```

the app.component.ts file where data$ is a BehaviorSubject

```
     import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


 interface Data {
 loading: string;
 }

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 title = 'MY-APP';

public data$: BehaviorSubject<Data> =
new BehaviorSubject<Data>({loading: 'Data Loading'});


 ngOnInit(): void {
 console.log();
 }
}
```

I just don't understand why i get the error of

"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEmbeddedView' of undefined
at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView"

when i try to embed the view from the setter
but from ngOnInit i am able to do it without any error

Comment: Have you tried to call the `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView` in the `ngAfterViewInit` method ?

Comment: @Michael Desigaud Yes I tried ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView in ngAfterViewInit, it works i mean i don't get undefined, same like in ngOnInit, But in ngAfterViewInit i get the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

Comment: i did not pay attention, i think its normal that you have undefined values in setter. The setter is called multiple times and the first time it should not be all defined (because of the Angular lifecycle cycle). I think the setter is called before the ngOnInit method. So either keep the ngOnInit method or add conditions in the setter.

Comment: You are right, the setter is called before the ngOnInit method, the other thing is i tried every possible condition to check before accessing it in the setter method, then i don't get error but nothing happens, i mean like void

Comment: Have you tried ngOnChanges ?

Comment: I just tried in ngOnChanges, and it works fine, no error, Thank you